# Spring Cloud Dataflow Cloudfoundry - Unversioned App Name

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-skipper

Is there a way to get unversioned app name in SCDF 2.9.X using skipper 2.8.x in CloudFoundry? With the current deployment in PCF, everytime we update/re-deploy a stream Skipper adds a **-v#**. This while great for blue/green sort of deployment, brings some challenge w.r.t monitoring. Is there a way to get consistent app name when we do a deployment using skipper 2.8.X? In some cases when we re-deploy the same stream, it increments the version number and this is a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

The naming of the deployed applications coincide with internal versioning of streams.

Can you describe how this is a hassle? We may be able to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi @Corneil, We monitor application logs and app health using splunk and with each deployment, when the version number changes, it becomes a hassle for monitoring. Also during deployment, if some of the apps do not start due to any issues, then we have to re-deploy part of the stream. At that point some apps within the sub-stream will have different versions to the apps that were successfully deployed. If there is a consistent app name in CloudFoundry that will help immensely. We are trying to migrate all our streams from 1.7.X to 2.9.X. So consistency will make our migration much more easier.

Comment: The metrics tags described here https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/streams/monitoring/ always remain the same.

Comment: Hi @Corneil, we have to have consistent app name in PCF for consistent monitoring. We are using splunk for our monitoring and that depends on the cloud foundry app name.